# How do I trigger WP CLI DB export using a PHP function?

Tags: functions, actions, wp-cli

I want to use WP-CLI to export a database - using `wp db export` - to create backups. I also need to use cron to control the backup schedule. WP-CLI is installed on my managed host, and I can use it via `SSH`, but I can't use `cron` directly on my server.

In order to use my own cron job to schedule the backups, I need to use the plugin WP Crontrol to add and edit `cron` jobs; that plugin uses functions as an `add_action`, i.e. `my_backup_cron` to fire `my_backup_function`:

This is the format the plugin uses:

`add_action( 'my_backup_cron', 'my_backup_function' );`

The function that runs a WP-CLI command can be a standard function, i.e. this in `functions.php`

```
function my_backup_function() {
    wp_mail( 'hello@example.com', 'WP Crontrol', 'WP Crontrol rocks!' );
}
```

But how do I turn a WP-CLI command - such as `wp --path=/var/www/ db export`, along with the path and other parameters - into a function like `my_backup_function`?

Answer (score 0):

WP-CLI can evaluate a PHP file.

See [`wp eval-file {PHP file name}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/eval-file/) for details, but essentially you:

1. Write a PHP file containing the commands you want executed in WordPress's context (let's say you call it `myfile.php`)
2. Run it using WP-CLI: `wp eval-file myfile.php`

If you need it scheduled, you could use `cron`, the Windows Scheduler, or whatever your local OS provided to schedule tasks.

### Update 1

On re-reading your question, this might be more what you're looking for (essentially you want to run a shell script at a scheduled time).

1. Create a shell script (let's suppose it's located at `/home/you/wp-backup.sh`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   /usr/local/bin/wp  --path=/var/www/ db export
   ```
2. Add that script to your `crontab` using [`crontab -e`](https://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference):

   ```
   0 0 * * * /bin/sh /home/you/wp-backup.sh
   ```

...which would run the job every day at midnight. (See the [`crontab` quick reference](https://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) for more options.)

This also assumes that the `sh` shell is located at `/bin/sh` and `wp` is at `/usr/local/bin/wp`. If not, please adjust the code accordingly.

### Update 2

From the comments, what you're looking for is how to emulate `wp db export` in a WordPress context. I'm afraid I have what may be bad news.

Looking into the [`wp db` source](https://github.com/wp-cli/db-command/blob/master/src/DB_Command.php), it appears that the [`export` command](https://github.com/wp-cli/db-command/blob/master/src/DB_Command.php#L529) essentially uses PHP's [`exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) command to run [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html). I don't think you'd be wise to emulate this -- I feel there are security experts who are cringing at just the thought of it.

There do exist WordPress backup plugins that can export your database; you can look into them (or, if they're open source, examine their code to see if anything in there can help you out).

Comment: Thanks, but I can't run cron on my server, that's why I need to use a plugin that adds cron capability. And the plugin uses the `add_action` format, so I'm trying to find out how to turn `wp --path=/var/www/ db export` into a function that goes in the theme's functions.php so I can call it via `add_action.`

Comment: Oh, OK, you're looking for what `wp db export` does under the hood. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's an idea, but I can't use backup plugins on the host; they create full file backups, but I want an extra database backup.

Comment: Sure, but they also often do full DB backups. For example, BackWPUp says it does DB backups (using mysqli). The code is here -- https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/backwpup/trunk/ . Perhaps you can find what you're looking for there.